# What are characteristic values for a piston pump?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

For a [piston pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piston_pump) you can calculate/measure things like,

- Average Volume flow rate (m³/s)
- Geometric Values (Surface)
- Pressure over time
- closing times of the valves
- energy conversion efficiency $\eta$

besides those, what charateristic values are there?

[image] (*example of a type of piston pump* [source](https://nationalvetcontent.edu.au/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/dc6a7f1f-e3d3-44d8-9bf1-984ea8cb3c01/204/pmaops201b/images/proc201_010100_g04.gif))

Comment: Are you looking for other ways to identify or classify the pumps?

Comment: Im looking for other values beside the described - You can use those to classify a pump, certainly. Or gauge the quality of a pump (in the case of energy conversion efficiency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some other criteria:

- Cycle time
- Piston speed
- Piston friction
- Device lifespan (most likely a function of the number of cycles completed)
- Number of suction/discharge ports
- Type of valves used

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

• Piston pump has a wide range of pressure
• It can manage force without the moving flow rate.
• The Pressure and flow rate variations have a small effect on the pump performance.
• It has the capability to move high viscosity fluids such as abrasives and slurries with an excellent design.
• Low speed.
• The fluid discharge doesn’t depend on the head. Due to this feature, these pumps can be used as metering pumps.
• This [type of pump](https://mechanicalboost.com/what-is-a-pump-types-of-pumps-and-applications/) has high efficiency